# Is it possible to create more than one instance in servicenow paid account?

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

In developer account,it is possible to create only one instance.
Is it possible to create more than one instance in servicenow paid account?.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  The number of instances a paying customer has is negotiated as part of their contract with ServiceNow.  Usually paying customers have a minimum of 3 instances:  Production, Quality Assurance, and Development.  Some customers have a 4th instance for testing new features, and some have even more.  I have worked in the past for a company that had 6 instances, and the company I am currently working with has 4.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Usually, people have one production instance and it depends on the plan they are on they might have one non-production instance or two. They can be a) Production b) Dev c) test. Some also have like two dev if they have multiple projects going at the same time or some playing around and testing new features/upragdes.